# CUDA kernel strange behavior, generating random values

Tags: c++, cuda, particle-system

I'm trying to simulate a spring-mass system with CUDA. Below is the kernel that updates the position of the particles:

```
__global__ void timestep(float3 *pos, float3 *pos_antiga, float3 *aceleracao, int numParticulas) {

    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if(index > (numParticulas - 1))
        return;
t
    float3 temp = pos[index];

    pos[index].x = pos[index].x + (pos[index].x - pos_antiga[index].x) * (1.0f - DAMPING) + aceleracao[index].x * TIMESTEP;
    pos[index].y = pos[index].y + (pos[index].y - pos_antiga[index].y) * (1.0f - DAMPING) + aceleracao[index].y * TIMESTEP;
    pos[index].z = pos[index].z + (pos[index].z - pos_antiga[index].z) * (1.0f - DAMPING) + aceleracao[index].z * TIMESTEP;

    pos_antiga[index] = temp;

}
```

The `pos` represents the 3D vector of the actual position, `pos_antiga` is the position in the previous time step, the `DAMPING` is 0.01 and `TIMESTEP` is 0.25. I'm using Verlet integration. In a system without any force, `aceleracao` is zero, so the `pos` and `pos_antigo` are the same before and after the kernel calls.

However, after the first iteration, CUDA returns crazy values for some axes, like 1.QNAN and -1.6241e+016. I think it's something related to block and thread sizes. The kernel call is below:

```
timestep<<<16, 16>>>(pos_d, pos_antiga_d, aceleracao_d, numParticulas);
```

So, what am I missing?

EDIT: Below is the caller code:

```
void timestepGPU(vector<Particula> *p) {

// vector<Particula> has all the particles of the system.

      // CPU
    float *pos;
    float *pos_antiga;
    float *aceleracao;

    // GPU
    float *pos_d;
    float *pos_antiga_d;
    float *aceleracao_d;

    // Number of particles
    int numParticulas = p->size();

    // Init
    pos = new float[numParticulas * 3];
    pos_antiga = new float[numParticulas * 3];
    aceleracao = new float[numParticulas * 3];

    // Transfering the values from the class to a plain vector
    vector<Particula>::iterator p_tmp;
    int i = 0;
    for(p_tmp = p->begin(); p_tmp != p->end(); p_tmp++)
    {
        pos[i] = (*p_tmp).getPos().f[0];
        pos[i + 1] = (*p_tmp).getPos().f[1];
        pos[i + 2] = (*p_tmp).getPos().f[2];

        pos_antiga[i] = (*p_tmp).getPosAntiga().f[0];
        pos_antiga[i + 1] = (*p_tmp).getPosAntiga().f[1];
        pos_antiga[i + 2] = (*p_tmp).getPosAntiga().f[2];

        aceleracao[i] = (*p_tmp).getAceleracao().f[0];
        aceleracao[i + 1] = (*p_tmp).getAceleracao().f[1];
        aceleracao[i + 2] = (*p_tmp).getAceleracao().f[2];

        i += 3;
    }

    // Here, I print the particle data BEFORE moving it to GPU
      cout << "PRINT PARTICLE DATA" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numParticulas * 3; i += 3) {
        cout << i/3 << " - Pos: " << pos[i] << " " << pos[i + 1] << " " << pos[i + 2] << " | Pos Ant: " << pos_antiga[i] << " " << pos_antiga[i + 1] << " " << pos_antiga[i + 2] << " | Acel: " << aceleracao[i] << " " << aceleracao[i + 1] << " " << aceleracao[i + 2] << endl;
    }
    cout << "END" << endl;

    // GPU
    ErroCUDA(cudaMalloc((void**) &pos_d, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float)));
    ErroCUDA(cudaMalloc((void**) &pos_antiga_d, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float)));
    ErroCUDA(cudaMalloc((void**) &aceleracao_d, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float)));

    // Moving data
    ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(pos_d, pos, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(pos_antiga_d, pos_antiga, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(aceleracao_d, aceleracao, numParticulas * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // Setting number of blocks and threads per block
    unsigned int numThreads, numBlocos;
    calcularGrid(numParticulas, 64, numBlocos, numThreads);
    //cout << numBlocos << "----------" << numThreads << endl;

    // Kernel
    timestep<<<numBlocos, numThreads>>>((float3 *) pos_d, (float3 *) pos_antiga_d, (float3 *) aceleracao_d, numParticulas);
    ErroCUDA(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Moving data back to the CPU
    ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(pos, pos_d, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(pos_antiga, pos_antiga_d, numParticulas * 3 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

      // Printing the particles' data AFTER Kernel call. At my GT 4xx, close to the 48th particle, it starts to show crazy values
    cout << "PARTICLE DATA" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numParticulas * 3; i += 3) {
        cout << i/3 << " - Pos: " << pos[i] << " " << pos[i + 1] << " " << pos[i + 2] << " | Pos Ant: " << pos_antiga[i] << " " << pos_antiga[i + 1] << " " << pos_antiga[i + 2] << " | Acel: " << aceleracao[i] << " " << aceleracao[i + 1] << " " << aceleracao[i + 2] << endl;
    }
    cout << "END" << endl;

    system("pause");

    i = 0;
    for(p_tmp = p->begin(); p_tmp != p->end(); p_tmp++)
    {
        if((*p_tmp).getMovel())
        {
            (*p_tmp).setPos(Vetor(pos[i], pos[i + 1], pos[i + 2]));
            (*p_tmp).setPosAntiga(Vetor(pos_antiga[i], pos_antiga[i + 1], pos_antiga[i + 2]));
(*p_tmp).setAceleracao(Vetor(0, 0, 0));
        }

        i += 3;
    }

    ErroCUDA(cudaFree(pos_d));
    ErroCUDA(cudaFree(pos_antiga_d));
    ErroCUDA(cudaFree(aceleracao_d));

    free(pos);
    free(pos_antiga);
    free(aceleracao);
}
```

In my example, attribute p has 100 items (10 x 10 particles). It's a mesh starting at (0, 0, 0) and goes to (20, 20, 20) in 3D space.

Thanks again everyone for the help!

Comment: SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  You haven't provided an SSCCE.org code.  Please provide a *complete* compilable reproducer of the problem.  Please also make sure you are doing [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all kernel launches and CUDA API calls.

Comment: I cannot spot anything obviously out of order. Does your code check the status of every CUDA API call and every kernel launch? Have you tried running it under cuda-memcheck?

Comment: You can try printing the values of pos and pos_antiga before and after your calculation for particular thread or index and check manually if the values are correct. Atleast you should be able to narrow down your problem with this.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all comments.

Comment: @RobertCrovella There is the caller code. The problem arises when, at the kernel, I add the "+ aceleracao[index] * TIMESTEP" to the formula. I'm running it from Visual Studio, Debug mode. As you can see, all CUDA checks are made.

Comment: @njuffa I ran this code in NSight to VS 2012, and no problem arise.

Comment: @SagarMasuti I already did that. As you can se the code, the values are printed before and after the kernel call.

Comment: @HerlesonPontes: I meant print inside the kernel for a particular index like first, middle and last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line..

```
 ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(aceleracao_d, aceleracao, numParticulas * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

should be ..

```
  ErroCUDA(cudaMemcpy(aceleracao_d, aceleracao, numParticulas * 3 *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Comment: Indeed, the number 3 was missing. Thank you for your answer! However, the acceleration of the system is zero. Does CUDA has "dirty" values for spaces that there is no value set, just like C? I'll check this modification soon, because now I'm not in front of a CUDA capable machine.

Comment: Yes!! The cudaMalloc documentation says: `cudaError_t cudaMalloc ( void **  devPtr,
size_t  size  
)` "Allocates size bytes of linear memory on the device and returns in *devPtr a pointer to the allocated memory. The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. **The memory is not cleared**. cudaMalloc() returns cudaErrorMemoryAllocation in case of failure."

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm beginning using CUDA for some researches, so my knowledge is not solid. I'll try this correction and see if this corrects everything. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. I didnt test it either.. Hopefully it solves your problem.